# How to select a row from a table and many rows from another (related) table

Tags: mysql, sql

im not good at "making" query. Let's say this is my db:

```
          artist                          pics
    -------------------       ---------------------------------------
    | id | name | age |       | id_artist | picUrl | picDescription |
    -------------------       ---------------------------------------
       |                          /\
       ----------------------------
```

I have to make a select to get a (single) artist with all its pics. The artist is always one and the pics are usually many.
Is there a way to get this data with just one query? After the query is made, how can I handle the table fields to retrieve their values?

I need to "print something like this"

michael jackson

-pics 1 blablabla

-pics 2 blablabla

-pics 3 blablabla

....

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.picUrl, B.picDescription
FROM artist A, pics B
WHERE A.id = B.id_artist;
```

Comment: Thank you. But now i can't understand how to "use" the outcome of the query. how can i create a loop that give me the artist and then all its related pic? I have to loop the outcome because i need to put it into some java object

Comment: for that you have to use the front end coding.

Comment: Yes i know, what i mean is how to loop the recordset correctly. If i "loop" the recordset now, i get this michael 1-jackson-img-concert....2-jackson-img-family... what i want is: 1-jackson-img-concert....2-img-family

Answer (score 0):

You should get numerous help if you have Googled around.

Anyways, You would want to use following query:

```
SELECT * from artist ar INNER JOIN pics p ON ar.id=p.id_artist
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use joins :

```
select * from artist a inner join pics p on a.id=p.id_artist
```

This query will not give you artists that do not have pics. To get them :

```
select * from artist a left join pics p on a.id=p.id_artist
```

Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

Use Joins:

```
SELECT a.*, b.picUrl, b.picDescription FROM artist a
INNER JOIN pics b on b.id_artist = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a inner join between these two tables. This will show all rows from both tables as long as there is a match.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM artist
INNER JOIN pics
ON artist.id=pics.id_artist;
```

Introduce a Where clause for a specific atrist if you only want to get a single value returned. E.g.

```
WHERE artist.id=001
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  id,
  `name`,
  picurl,
  picdescription 
FROM
  artist 
  INNER JOIN pics 
    ON artist.`id` = pics.`id_artist` ;
```